# Python / How decorating a method part of a class without modifying said class?

Tags: python, decorator

**MAIN TROUBLE**

As an example, say I would like to decorate `split()` method of `str` class
(the example is representative of what I try to do, except I would like to decorate `agg` method of pandas `DataFrame` class).

At least, I get the same error.

I prefer not to use `@` nor to create a child of `str` class to keep things simple (and maybe it is why it is not working...)

I encounter following trouble.

```
def bla_addition(word):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Modify `my_list`
            word2 = word + 'bla'
            return  word2.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

added = bla_addition('blu')
split = added(str.split)
new_word = split('l')
```

Error encountered: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'func'`

Please, do you have any idea how I could do?

I thank you for your help and advices.

PS: I took the way of using decorator without `@` here: 
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php
I find it very helpful to avoid having to create a new 1-line function for `split`.

**SIDE QUESTION**

As a side question, I initially used this code. It turns out that it is not possible to modify a parameter of the decorator. Am I understanding correctly?

```
def bla_addition(word):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Modify `my_list`
            word += 'bla'                #-> parameter word modified
            return  word.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

added = bla_addition('blu')
split = added(str.split)
new_word = split('l')
```

Error generated: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'word' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Why would `func` exist on `word`?

Comment: Note that decoration is a syntactic concept. `bla_addition` is just a higher-order function (which is a function that either takes a function as an argument or returns a function); decoration is the use of `@bla_addition def foo():...` as a shortcut for `def foo():...; foo = bla_addition(foo)`. The issue here is that the assignment creates a new local variable named `word` that shadows the parameter of `bla_addition`. You can use the `nonlocal` keyword to fix that, but the issue remains that `str` values are immutable.

Comment: @PeterWood   In this case, `func` directs toward function `split` that does exist for string. At least this is the idea. This is where the trouble is I guess. Can we decorate a method of a class this way? (I understand `split` is a method of class `str`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just found out thanks to this explanation: https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_differences_between_static_method_and_class_method_instance_method.php

*Another way of calling is by going through the class name as shown below:*

Here is the working code.

```
def bla_addition(word):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            # Modify `my_list`
            word2 = word + 'bla'
            return  func(word2, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

added = bla_addition('blu')
split = added(str.split)
new_word = split('l')
```

Bests,